# Autoresizing mask in xib misbehaves when y origin set to 0

Tags: ios, xib

I have designed my xib to have an an innerview embedded in an outer view. Set the layout to 3.5 inch. I need the outerview to expand in height on a 4 inch screen and the innerview to move down by a corresponding distance.
Below are the images for the xib layout and the size inspector for the two views

Question - When the innerView y origin is set to 0, it drops down to the bottom of the screen when running on 4 inch. However if I set the **y origin of the inner view to 1 (or higher) everything is fine**. Why is this happening. I am not using autolayout.

**xib layout**

[image: xib layout]

**Outer view size inspector**
[image: Outerview masks]

**Inner view size inspector**
[image: InnerView masks]

**When run on 4 inch display**
[image: Resulting view on 4 inch]

Comment: I've struggled like crazy trying to get autoresizing to work between device sizes in IB with or without autolayout. With autolayout it becomes a little more manageable, but without it the device can have trouble determining where you want the inner view to be relative to. The unfortunate best bet is usually to handle static displays like this via code or autolayout. You can set one version in IB and then adjust as needed if the device bounds height is 568 via code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it would work only for a non-zero Y coordinate.

Anyway, it sounds like you want InnerView to stay the same distance from the bottom edge of its superview, and to stay the same height.  So you need to set InnerView's autoresizing mask to have a flexible top margin, a fixed height, and a fixed bottom margin:

[image: autoresizing with flexible top margin]

Comment: Thanks for responding Rob. The innerView is not at a fixed distance from bottom. It should move down as the outer view height increases (exactly as it shows in the example window in size inspector). It works as expected if y origin is set to anything other than 0.